# Rails 4.2: datetime attribute not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, console

I'm using an attribute named `:subscription_active_untill` in my user table, its type is `datetime`, I'm trying to save a datetime stamp in it but it is not being saved. For example, executing current command in rails console

```
User.find(3).update(:subscription_active_untill => 1473363930)
```

it returns `true` in console but when I see the record using `User.find(3)` the `:subscription_active_untill` attribute is still `nill`. What could be the issue?

**Note:** I can update any other attribute of the same record without any issue, the problem is with this specific attribute.

Comment: what if you pass a standard datetime format? smtg like `2001-02-03T04:05:06+00:00`

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I had to submit in UTC format instead of UNIX timestamp. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved, above I was trying to save wrong format for the datetime (i.e. unix timestamp format). I had to convert it to correct format. So, doing following commands saves the attribute correctly.

```
User.find(3).update(:subscription_active_untill => 2016-09-08 20:14:30 UTC)
```

To convert UNIX timestamo to UTC format we can use following code:

```
Time.at(1473363930).utc
```